# Bash: Cut current path until a certain folder

Tags: linux, bash

lets say I have three bash files in different directories:

```
/a/b/c/d/e/f/script1.sh
/a/bb/c/d/script2.sh
/aa/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/script3.sh
```

If I call $(pwd) I get the path of the current directory. Is there a way to somehow "crop" this path until a certain folder? In the following an example is shown if the certain folder would be called "c":

- In the case of script1.sh I would like to have the path: /a/b/c
- In the case of script2.sh I would like to have the path: /a/bb/c
- In the case of script3.sh I would like to have the path: /aa/b/c

Thank you for your help

Comment: `$PWD` is already a variable, no need to use a subshell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume what you want is parameter expansion :

```
$ path="/a/b/c/d/e/f/script1.sh"
$ echo "${path#*/c}"
/d/e/f/script1.sh
```

#### Edit

Inversed :

```
$ path="/a/b/c/d/e/f/script1.sh"
$ echo "${path%/d*}"
/a/b/c
```

Regards!

Comment: Can I also get the "inverse" with this? /a/b/c/

Comment: @Henri74 Done. Take into account that im assuming /d is always a subfolder of /c. Otherwise I can come up with a different solution.

Comment: @Henri74 If you happen not to know whats coming under /c, you can also use this : 
$ path="/a/b/c/d/e/f/script1.sh"
$ echo "$path" | sed -E 's#(/a/b/c)(.*)#\1#g'
/a/b/c

Comment: note that in case of multiple `/d` to remove largest suffix `${path%%/d*}`

Comment: What if some joker creates a directory tree like `somedata/old/old/old` ?

Answer (score 1):

Bash regex:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ "$PWD" =~ (^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)(.*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

It returns the first three components of your path (if there are three components). You could also set the path tp for example `$pwd` and:

```
$ pwd=/a/b/c/d/e/f/script1.sh
$ [[ "$pwd" =~ (^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)(.*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
/a/b/c
```

Also, pay notice to @123's comment below; that is the correct way, my mind was off. Thank you, sir.

Comment: Could rewrite simpler as `[[ "$PWD" =~ (/[^/]+){3} ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH}`

Answer (score 1):

Use [cut](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/) command:

```
echo '/a/b/c/d/e/f/script1.sh' | cut -d '/' -f 1-4
echo '/a/bb/c/d/script2.sh' | cut -d '/' -f 1-4
echo '/aa/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/script3.sh' | cut -d '/' -f 1-4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC h]$ pwd
/home/sahaquiel/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
[sahaquiel@sahaquiel-PC h]$ pwd | cut -d"/" -f1-6
/home/sahaquiel/a/b/c
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a situation like this:

```
$ pwd
/a/b/c/d/cc/e/c/f

$ FOLDER=c
```

You could use [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) on the `$PWD` variable like this:

```
$ echo "${PWD%/${FOLDER}/*}/${FOLDER}"
/a/b/c/d/cc/e/c

$ echo "${PWD%%/${FOLDER}/*}/${FOLDER}"
/a/b/c
```

The difference is in the single or double `%`. With `%` the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter (`${PWD}`) with the shortest matching pattern. With `%%` it will be the longest matching pattern.

Just make sure you'll enclose the `${FOLDER}` variable with forward slashes, because otherwise it could match directories that contain the match in their name (like in this example the directory `cc`)

Because you would like to include the folder you were looking for, it's included at the end of the string, prefixed with a forward slash.